# How to display grid view based on the selection of three dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have three dropdown list one for name, other month and other is year values. when I select name in dropdown list grid view display values of selected name. when I select month it has to display according to the month. when I select both name and month it has to display according to that. when I select all the three grid view has to shows the values for that condition.
Now am binding the data for dropdown list and grid view is in code behind file.
How to achieve that?
Guide me for ASPX and C# coding.

Comment: Use selectedIndex changed event for each of these dropdowns and Bindyour datasource to grid by passing parameters like name,month and year

Comment: You'll be much more successful getting help if you demonstrate what you have tried and where you are having trouble.

Comment: Post the query for populating the grid view.

Comment: And alsoi like sum  salary details like ha,da hra shown in grid view and to display the sum to that respective footer

Answer (score 0):

I achieve that by using following coding.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sivConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EMPNAME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),SALDATE,113),BAS_SAL,BASPAY,ADJ,DA,HRA,MA,TOT_SAL,EPF,FA,CATUP,NET_SAL from salentry where empname ='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' or DATEPART(MONTH,saldate)='" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "' or DATEPART(YEAR,saldate)='"+DropDownList3.SelectedValue+"'", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();`
```

Do you have idea better than that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a dynamic function which accepts the parameters as you select the choices from the drop down.

```
public void BindGridView(string Name, string Month, string year)
{
//logic to fetch the data
}
```

Then you have to check the parameters are null or not. Based on these results you can put the queries to fetch the data.